# Unsupported driver [mongodb] laravel 5.4.36

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I try to connect the Laravel 5.4.36 with mongodb

My mongo db version  `v3.4.16`
installed

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb:3.2.0
jenssegers/mongodb-session
jenssegers/mongodb-sentry
```

config/app.php

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
```

#### Mymodel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Mymodel extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'addresses';
}
```

#### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mymodel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ConnectmongoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $node = Mymodel::all();
        echo "hi";
    }
}
```

#### config/database.php

```
'mongodb' => [
                'driver'   => 'mongodb',
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'port'     =>  27017,
                'database' => 'mydb',
                'username' => 'usrename',
                'password' => 'password',
                'options'  => [
                    'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
                ]
],
```

#### phpinfo

[image]

While i call the controller function
it shows the error

> 1/1) InvalidArgumentException
> Unsupported driver [mongodb]
>
> in ConnectionFactory.php line 286

I am not able to find where i did mistake/Miss any steps.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB Extension ^1.5 does not support mongoDB 2.6

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/#mongodb-compatibility

Comment: Updated my mongodb version to 3.4.16 still i got the same error Unsupported driver [mongodb]

Comment: resolved the error . now it says Authentication failed. I provide correct users username and password. I dont know why i got the error